React Beautiful DND reorder api call
I'm implementing drag-and-drop functionality using react-beautiful-dnd in my React/TypeScript application. The goal is to drag Product components and drop them into Folder components. Upon drop, I make an API call to move the product into the target folder.
const FolderNode = memo(({ node }: { node: ExtendedTreeViewBaseItem }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const splitLocation = location.pathname.split("/")[1];

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        overflowY: "auto",
        maxHeight: "500px", // Adjust based on your UI
      }}
    >
      <Droppable
        droppableId={`folder-${node.id.toString()}`}
        type={splitLocation}
        isDropDisabled={false}
        isCombineEnabled={false}
        renderClone={(provided, snapshot, rubric) => (
          <div
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            style={{
              ...provided.draggableProps.style,
              opacity: snapshot.isDragging ? 0.7 : 1,
            }}
          >
            <span>Cloned Item: {rubric.source.index}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      >
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <>
            <div
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              data-level={node.level || 0}
              data-node-type="folder"
              className={s.each_node}
              style={{
                minHeight: "40px", // Fixed height for each folder node
                boxSizing: "border-box",
                position: "relative", // Avoid layout shifts
              }}
            >
              <FolderIcon />
              <span>{node.label}</span>
              {/* <div className={s.placeholder}>{provided.placeholder}</div> */}
              {snapshot.isDraggingOver && <div style={{ height: "20px" }} />}{" "}
              {/* Custom placeholder */}
            </div>
            {/* <div className={s.placeholder} style={{ height: "20px", overflow: "hidden" }}></div> */}
          </>
        )}
      </Droppable>

      {node.children &&
        node.children.map((child) => (
          <FolderNode key={child.id} node={child as ExtendedTreeViewBaseItem} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
});

export default NavFolderTreeStructure;

this is part of my nav it looks something like that navigation folders
when I drag my product on to the folder I want to drop it and make an API call
problem is that the
{provided.placeholder}

is acting strange , most likely due to the products original size, placeholders size and issue
I have tried to set the size or hide placeholder but then I can only drop the product to the folder (index 0 ) as there is some issue with me going down the list , I have to leave the container and then go back into it to be able to select from the list moving upwards.
this is my product list component
  <FilterComponent
            endpoint="/creator/2d/templates"
            defaultSort="id"
            defaultPagination={20}
            isPagination={true}
            category_id={currentFolderId?.toString()}
            render={({ data, onDelete }) => (
              <Droppable
                droppableId="product-list"
                type={splitLocation}
                isCombineEnabled={false}
                isDropDisabled={true}
              >
                {(provided) => (
                  <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                    <div className={s.map_container}>
                      {data?.map((el: any, i: number) => (
                        <Draggable
                          key={`dashboard-product-products-all-map-${el.id}`}
                          draggableId={`product-${el.id}`}
                          index={i}
                        >
                          {(provided, snapshot) => {
                            const transform = provided.draggableProps.style?.transform || "";
                            return (
                              <div
                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                {...provided.draggableProps}
                                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                style={{
                                  ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                                  transform: snapshot.isDragging
                                    ? `${transform} scale(0.3)` // Combine translate and scale
                                    : transform,
                                  transition: "transform 0.1s ease",
                                }}
                              >
                                <ProductComponent
                                  product={el}
                                  variant="medium"
                                  handleClick={(variant) => projectHandler(variant, el)}
                                  componentOptions="1"
                                  id={`dashboard-product-products-all-map-${el.id}`}
                                  onDelete={onDelete}
                                  isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                                  isDnD={true}
                                />
                              </div>
                            );
                          }}
                        </Draggable>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ display: "none" }}>{provided.placeholder}</div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </Droppable>
            )}
          />

it's is my DragDrop wrapper

const Layout = ({ children }: ILayout) => {
  const { folderPath, setFolderPath, setForceFetchFolder } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { sendRequest } = useApiRequest();
  const location = useLocation();
  const splitLocation = location.pathname.split("/")[1];
  const notification = useNotification();
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  // State to store the currently hovered folder ID during drag
  const [hoveredFolderId, setHoveredFolderId] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleDragEnd = async (result: DropResult) => {
    const { source, destination, draggableId } = result;

    if (!destination) return;
    // If dropped in the same place, do nothing
    if (source.droppableId === destination.droppableId && source.index === destination.index) {
      return;
    }

    // We can use the hoveredFolderId if we know that the destination is a folder droppable
    if (hoveredFolderId && hoveredFolderId.startsWith("folder-")) {
      await handleMoveToFolder(draggableId, hoveredFolderId);
    } else if (destination.droppableId === "product-list") {
      // Handle dropping into product-list or other droppables if needed
    }

    // Reset hovered folder after drop
    setHoveredFolderId(null);
  };

  const handleMoveToFolder = async (draggableId: string, droppableId: string) => {
    console.log({ draggableId, droppableId });
    // Extract the folder ID from the droppable ID
    const folderId = droppableId.replace("folder-", "");

    // Extract item type and ID from draggableId
    const [itemType, itemId] = draggableId.split("-");

    // Map item type to API paths
    const apiPaths: Record<string, string> = {
      product: "templates",
      project: "projects",
    };

    // Determine the correct API path
    const apiPath = apiPaths[itemType];
    if (!apiPath) {
      console.error(`Invalid item type: ${itemType}`);
      return;
    }

    // Send the request to move the item
    const response = await sendRequest("put", `creator/2d/${apiPath}/${itemId}`, {
      category_id: folderId,
    });

    // Trigger folder refresh
    setForceFetchFolder((prevState) => !prevState);

    if (response) {
      notification({
        id: uniqueID,
        type: "SUCCESS",
        message: t(`${itemType} moved succesfully ${folderId}`),
      });
    }
  };

  const onDragUpdate = (update: DragUpdate) => {
    const { destination } = update;
    console.log(destination, "destination");
    if (destination) {
      const { droppableId } = destination;
      // If hovered over a folder droppable zone, store its ID
      if (droppableId.startsWith("folder-")) {
        setHoveredFolderId(droppableId);
      } else {
        setHoveredFolderId(null);
      }
    } else {
      // If not hovering over any droppable
      setHoveredFolderId(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.container}>
      <TopBar />
      <div className={s.children}>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd} onDragUpdate={onDragUpdate}>
          <MainNav />
          <div
            style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", width: "100%", marginLeft: "10px" }}
          >
            <Breadcrumbs styleOption={1} folderPath={folderPath} setFolderPath={setFolderPath} />
            {children}
          </div>
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;


ideal solution would be drag product over a folder no placeholders no extra space appears,
I drop it make API call that's it,

I am not sure but can it be this line the problem maybe from the div node, maybe use display:flex: on that style attribute style={{minHeight: "40px", boxSizing: "border-box", position: "relative"}} 

Or try to put in span also the placeholder : <span>{node.label}</span> <span className={s.placeholder}>{provided.placeholder}</span>

@Kev74 After analyzing the code, I found the solution. I needed to make the ProductComponent smaller in the onBeforeCapture callback so that its width and height are recalculated when the item becomes draggable. By ensuring the item is smaller than the droppable area's placeholder, I was able to eliminate the bug.
For anyone struggling with a similar issue, make sure to check the width and height of the draggable item in relation to the placeholder of the drop area!
